# how to run local shell script over ssh with su option

Tags: command-line, ssh

I have a script called test_ms.sh which I want to run over ssh along with the su - username option.

I am user X on server A and server B and I have su access to user Y on server B. I do not have direct access to user Y.

Now, I want to execute the script located on server A as user Y on the remote server B.

If I run the script via ssh as user X s it works fine

```
ssh X@B 'sh -s' < test_ms.sh
```

However, If I run the script as user B on server Y from server A through user X, it doesn't work.

I am using following approach to execute the script.

```
ssh X@B su Y -c 'sh -s' < test_ms.sh
```

Please suggest how to accomplish this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain some more. Should I assume that you need to use userX and then switch to userY because only userX (whi is not root) has ssh access? Unless you are logging in as `root`, you will need userY's password to `su`. Do you have `root` access to the remote machine? Can you tweak the `sudoers` file for example? How does your approach fail? Do you want to avoid having to type a password?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are not logging on as `root` otherwise this would work. If so, you also hav the target user's password. So, why are you fiddling about with `su` instead of logging in as that user directly? If the target user on the remote machine is `bob`, connact using that name:

```
ssh bob@host ./test_ms.sh
```

or

```
ssh bob@host sh -s < /test_ms.sh
```

Comment: if I have the target user's password I would have used that user to ssh and execute the script. However, In my case; the user which is running the ssh has su access to the target user. Therefore I need to find a way to execute the script over ssh as su